# Angular UI Router new view, same URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I have the following state defined in my Angular app and I'm wondering if it's possible to inject a template from another state into the current state?

In my `.catch()` below I have: `$state.go('error404');` which will trigger the error404 state and redirect the user to /404. However what I'd like to happen is that the user stays on the same URL that triggered the 404 and the 404 template is just injected on to the page. (so no redirect). Is this possible?

```
.state('error404', {
        url: '/404',
        template: '<p style="color:white;">404 NOT FOUND</p>'
    })

.state('publicUserProfile', {
        url: '/:username',
        templateUrl: 'views/public-profile.html',
        controller: 'publicProfileController',
        resolve: {
            userData: ['$http', 'API_URL', '$stateParams', '$state', function ($http, API_URL, $stateParams, $state) {
                return $http
                .get(API_URL + '/users/' + $stateParams.username)
                .catch(function () {
                    $state.go('error404'); <-- HERE
                })
            }]
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `url` attribute in this case:

```
.state('error404', {
        template: '<p style="color:white;">404 NOT FOUND</p>'
    })
```

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that? Thanks!